# Change column layout only for the first row in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web page that consists with video/image content and I have them display four on each row.

I would like to make the first row a featured section with a different column configuration as illustrated below.

[image]

So this special row will have 3 columns with the first one in a larger size.

Below is what I currently have and `<li>` represents a row and `<figure>` represents a column.

```
 <ul>
    <li>
    <% Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { %>

        <% if (key%4 == 0 && key != 0) { %>
            </li><li>
        <% } %>
        <figure>

          ...

        </figure>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

I just can't get my head around adding this condition within the loop.

Comment: The first step is getting a CSS class or ID for an element to be two columns wide

Comment: Yes..adding CSS class is considered done here. Just forgot to mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your CSS setup correctly so that a `<figure>` element with class `featured` gets the correct double-width

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <% Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { %>
        <% if ((key + 1)%4 == 0) { %>
            </li><li>
        <% } %>
        <figure <% if (key == 0) { %> class="featured" <% } %> >

          ...

        </figure>
    <% }) %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. I never thought of adding if condition inside the tag. Just one thing though, `</li><li>` never gets executed which I believe it's because `<% if ((key + 1)%4 == 0) { %>` is never true. But I don't get it, this condition should pass.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: is your key a string or an integer (I assumed it would be an integer)?

Comment: Because if you are having a string key adding 1 to it may not give the results you expect: 

`("3" + 1) => "31"` 
`(parseInt("3") + 1) => 4`

Comment: `<% if (key%4 == 0 && key != 0) { %>` worked before so I assumed it was integer. How do I console.log or alert in embed in .ejs file? (embed html)

Comment: You can add a console.log statement anywhere between the <% and %> as long as it is correct javascript. Now in the comments I cannot use newlines, but you should get the idea `<% console.log(key +1); if ((key + 1) % 4 ...... `

Comment: Oh..I looked at browser inspector when I should look at the Terminal console. I just printed all keys and they are just like 0, 1, 2, 3 ... but if I do `console.log(key+1)` it will print `01, 11, 21, 31...`  Why is that? It looks integer so I don't get it.  The printed value is not wrapper in `" "` so I how do I know this is integer or string?

Comment: Then it is definitely a string (it is not an addition, but a concatenation), just change the code in the first if statement to `if ((parseInt(key) + 1) % 4 == 0)` and it should work. Obviously since you are treating your key as an integer anyway, it would make more sense to convert your key to an integer as the first step and then use the integer value in all the comparison.

Comment: Thank you. Does console normally print without string, integer differentiation?

Comment: The console always prints Strings, converting the object you passed to it to a string using the object's `toString()` method.

Comment: I see. Thank a lot. I learned a good deal from your contribution!